# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () why?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, axios

I am building an app in which the user can input cars into the API app and delete them, but I am getting a 404 error when trying to delete a car. what I don't understand is that I can access the car endpoint without problems but I get a delete 404 error.
this is the delete code:

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import styles from './DeleteCar.module.css';

const DeleteCarUi = ({
  id, image, model, year, cars, setCars,
}) => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  // const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const removeCar = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://dreamcars2.onrender.com/api/v1/car/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        let filteredCars = [];
        filteredCars = cars.filter((car) => car.id !== id);
        setCars(filteredCars);
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setErrorMessage(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p className={`${styles.errorMsg} fs-5`}>{errorMessage}</p>
      <section className={`${styles.carCnt} mx-4`} key={id}>
        <div className={styles.imgCnt}>
          <img src={image} alt={model} className={styles.carImg} />
        </div>
        <div className="model-detail d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <h3 className="h4 mt-3">{model}</h3>
          <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center gap-0 mt-0">
            <h5 className="h6 pt-1">{year}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => removeCar(id)}
          className="btn btn-danger mb-3"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

DeleteCarUi.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  model: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  year: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  cars: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object])).isRequired,
  setCars: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default DeleteCarUi;
```

this is the car controller:

```
 def delete
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    if @car.destroy
      render json: { success: 'The car has been deleted successfully' }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'There was an error, please try again!' }, status: :internal_server_error
    end
  end
```

and this is the routes code:

```
 # Car endpoints
  get 'api/v1/cars', to: 'cars#index'
  get 'api/v1/car/:id', to: 'cars#show'
  post 'api/v1/car', to: 'cars#create'
  delete 'api/v1/car/:id', to: 'cars#delete'
  get 'api/v1/reserve/cars/:start_date', to: 'cars#reserve'
  get 'api/v1/cars/:user_id', to: 'cars#user_cars'
```

Comment: You have not posted the backend code for the delete action.

Comment: this is the cars controller:

Comment: `def destroy
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    if @car.destroy
      render json: { success: 'The car has been deleted successfully' }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: 'There was an error, please try again!' }, status: :internal_server_error
    end
  end`

Comment: No, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I have done so...

Comment: it is working now. there was a problem with car controller. it def destroy instead of def delete. thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: @ArturGouveia Please mark this question as closed, answered, deleted, or delete it, etc.